# How can I paste fiile links in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I use Notepad++ to paste URLs of websites that I find helpful instead of using bookmarks as I can also add text that gives reference about that URL.

[image]

If there are any files that I am working on, such as PDFs or other TXT files, I have to paste them on my desktop.

Is there any way I can link these file locations to my notepad++ similar to URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Use a browser to get file locations.

If you use a browser to open PDF files, you will get a link in place of a URL starting with `file:///`.

You can paste this link in your notepad++ txt file and it will be clickable and also open the file in your system.

This also works with other text files, image files, and even video files.

You can open(only for link) any type of file on your browser using `Open with..`

In the case of video files, your browser will most probably try to download the video. But you can cancel that and get the link from Downloads.

[image]